# Reading config file in Apache module

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2-module

I am developing apache module . I want to read some data from my own config file . How to read the config file in Apache . I am using C language to develop the module.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid it, because Apache provides you with a sophisticated configuration mechanism. If you insist on doing it, register a post_config hook and do C programming 101 I/O to read a file and parse it.

Comment: could you give me a example.

Comment: Download Apache's source code and look at any standard module.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . Now I am able to read config file .

Comment: @sumitchansouliya I am facing similar issue. Could you direct me to right resource? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `ap_config.h` in your c code.

```
ap_config_file *fl;
apr_pool_t *pl;
location = "location of your file";
apr_pool_create(&pl,NULL);
if(ap_pcfg_openfile(&fl,pl,location)==APR_SUCCESS){
/* do your stuff here */
}
```